# Using Google Apps Script to copy .CSV file data to Google Sheets

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am needing to loop through each .CSV file in a source folder and copy the data from each file into a new sheet/tab in one Google Sheets file. I've found a couple of answers related to this topic but I'm getting errors with both code sets. Here's the code I'm attempting to build a solution from:

```
function appendCSV() {  
    var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("myCSVFile.csv").next(); 
    var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString()); 
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
    var lastRow=sheet.getLastRow(); 
    sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
}
```

Here's the first error I'm getting:

> *Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end. (line 2, file "Code")*

I can delete the `.next()` method from line 2 and then I get another error:

> *TypeError: Cannot find function getBlob in object FileIterator. (line 3, file "Code")*

Can anyone identify what might be going wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to  provide Spreadsheet Id and folder id.  Also you may wish to change the sheet names of the created sheets/tabs.

```
function loadCSVFilesIntoSheets() { 
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('SpreadsheetId')
  var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById('folderId');
  var files=folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.CSV);
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    var file=files.next();
    var vA=Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
    var ts=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss")
    var sh=ss.insertSheet(file.getName()+'-'+ts);
    sh.getRange(1,1,vA.length,vA[0].length).setValues(vA);
  }
}
```

Getting Spreadsheet Id: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SpreadsheetIdHere/edit#gid=1655026329`

Folder Id:
`https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/folder id here`

[DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app)

[Utilities.parseCsv()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parseCsv(String))

[Utilities.formatDate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String))

Comment: Thank you for the response!! Much appreciated. I inserted a spreadsheet ID and folder ID as you suggested. When I run the code, I get this error:

"Missing ; before statement. (line 10, file "Code")"

which is the last line of code.

Comment: Sorry I fixed it.  Last minute change.

Comment: That works! Thank you so much! Another question: How can I open both the folder and file by name instead of by ID. I tried open() instead of the openByID(), but that didn't seem to work - says it 'cannot find method open()'. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Id's are more meaningfull in Google Drive.  Infact, it's not unusual to find files with  the same name within the same directory.  The only command in DriveApp to  get the files by  name is Folder.getFilesByName() which return an iterator for the set.  If you know for an absolute fact that it's the only file with  that name then you  can get it with `var file=Folder.getFilesByName().next();

Answer (score 1):

The first error that you are getting

> Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end. (line 2, file "Code")

occurs because apparently there isn't any file named `myCSVFile.csv`

```
var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("myCSVFile.csv").next();
```

The second error occurs for the same reason.

First, you should double check that the filename is correct and that this file is owned or shared with the same account used to run the script.